# Oracle SQL - Nested Select Statements for duplicating a column with different results

Tags: sql, oracle

I've a problem with a bit of Oracle SQL code whereby I have a column called "Description" and it relates to the description of the Segments 1-4 from the GL_Code_Combinations table. I've managed to get the first segment description working (albeit it not in the correct way I believe) but when I try to use a nested select statement to bring back segment description 2-4 it errors out saying i'm missing an expression.

Below is the code I currently have and the code I've found that seems to provide the results I want when i merge it with my already existing code and not put it as a nested select function.

ORIGINAL CODE

```
SELECT DISTINCT
AID.INVOICE_ID,
AID.AMOUNT,
AID.PERIOD_NAME,
GCC.SEGMENT1 AS Organisation,
GCC.SEGMENT2 AS ServiceArea,
GCC.SEGMENT3 AS AccountCode,
GCC.SEGMENT4 AS SubAccount,
INV.INVOICE_NUM,
INV.CREATION_DATE,
PO.SEGMENT1 as PO_Number,
SUP.VENDOR_NAME AS Supplier_Name,
--AID.LINE_TYPE_LOOKUP_CODE,
LINES.LINE_NUMBER,
LINES.DESCRIPTION,
SUP.SEGMENT1 as Supplier_Number,
**fvv.DESCRIPTION AS EntityDesc**



FROM AP_INVOICES_All INV
INNER JOIN  AP_INVOICE_LINES_ALL LINES 
  ON INV.INVOICE_ID = LINES.INVOICE_ID 
INNER JOIN  AP_INVOICE_DISTRIBUTIONS_ALL AID 
  ON INV.INVOICE_ID = AID.INVOICE_ID 

--LEFT JOIN AP_INVOICE_LINES_ALL LINES 
  --ON PO_HEADERS_ALL.PO_HEADER_ID = LINES.PO_HEADER_ID

RIGHT JOIN PO_HEADERS_ALL PO 
  ON LINES.PO_HEADER_ID = PO.PO_HEADER_ID

LEFT JOIN PO_DISTRIBUTIONS_ALL PDA 
  ON PO.PO_HEADER_ID = PDA.PO_HEADER_ID
INNER JOIN  GL_CODE_COMBINATIONS GCC
  ON GCC.CODE_COMBINATION_ID = nvl(PDA.CODE_COMBINATION_ID,          AID.DIST_CODE_COMBINATION_ID)
INNER JOIN
  POZ_SUPPLIERS_V SUP 
  ON INV.VENDOR_ID = SUP.VENDOR_ID,
**FND_KF_SEGMENTS_VL FKS,
FND_VS_VALUES_VL FVV** 

WHERE AID.LINE_TYPE_LOOKUP_CODE NOT IN (  'REC_TAX',  'NONREC_TAX')
AND LINES.LINE_TYPE_LOOKUP_CODE NOT IN ('TAX')
**AND FVV.VALUE = gcc.segment1 
AND FVV.value_set_id = FKS.default_value_set_id 
AND FKS.segment_code = 'Entity' 
AND FKS.column_name = 'SEGMENT1'**

ORDER BY
AID.INVOICE_ID,
LINES.LINE_NUMBER
```

The code I added was:

```
(SELECT fvv.DESCRIPTION
    FROM FND_KF_SEGMENTS_VL FKS,
    FND_VS_VALUES_VL FVV
    WHERE FVV.VALUE=gcc.segment1
    AND FVV.value_set_id=FKS.default_value_set_id
    AND FKS.segment_code='Entity'
    AND FKS.column_name='SEGMENT1')
    as EntityDescription
```

and the entire string I want to add is:

```
(SELECT fvv.DESCRIPTION
FROM FND_KF_SEGMENTS_VL FKS,
                         FND_VS_VALUES_VL FVV
                    WHERE FVV.VALUE=gcc.segment1
                    AND FVV.value_set_id=FKS.default_value_set_id
                    AND FKS.segment_code='Entity'
                    AND FKS.column_name='SEGMENT1')
                                                             as EntityDescription,
             (SELECT fvv.DESCRIPTION
                    FROM FND_KF_SEGMENTS_VL FKS,
                         FND_VS_VALUES_VL FVV
                    WHERE FVV.VALUE=gcc.segment2
                    AND FVV.value_set_id=FKS.default_value_set_id
                    AND FKS.segment_code='Service Area'
                    AND FKS.column_name='SEGMENT2')
                                                            as ServiceAreaDescription,
             (SELECT fvv.DESCRIPTION
                    FROM FND_KF_SEGMENTS_VL FKS,
                         FND_VS_VALUES_VL FVV
                    WHERE FVV.VALUE=gcc.segment3
                    AND FVV.value_set_id=FKS.default_value_set_id
                    AND FKS.segment_code='Account'
                    AND FKS.column_name='SEGMENT3')
                                                            as AccountDescription,
             (SELECT fvv.DESCRIPTION
                    FROM FND_KF_SEGMENTS_VL FKS,
                         FND_VS_VALUES_VL FVV
                    WHERE FVV.VALUE=gcc.segment4
                    AND FVV.value_set_id=FKS.default_value_set_id
                    AND FKS.segment_code='Sub Account'
                    AND FKS.column_name='SEGMENT4')
                                                            as SubAccountDescription
```

as it should give me the descriptions from the FND_KF_SEGMENTS_VL FKS,
                             FND_VS_VALUES_VL FVV tables which marry up with Segment 1 - 4 from the GL_CODE_COMBINATIONS table

I've searched the forums and can't quite see something that explains how I can get it to work. Would greatly appreciate some help on where i've been going wrong

Regards,

Matt